# How to show dividers after some items in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm building a list that is sorted alphabetically. The list should show a divider containing the Letter that the following icons belong to.

I'm using a Cursoradapter that contains the already sorted result from the database.
I plan on adding the divider to the list item and set it to visible if the shown letter changes. How do I know that I have a new Letter? Is there a better way then going forward or backward in the cursor and check if the item I show is the end or beginning of a new group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in SQL query that provides data for Cursor.

Suppose we have `person(name varchar)` table.

Instead of asking just:

```
SELECT name FROM person ORDER BY name;
```

one can query:

```
SELECT p.name, CASE(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM person 
    WHERE name<p.name and SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)=SUBSTR(p.name,1 , 1)
    ) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END isFirst 
FROM person p 
ORDER BY name;
```

that gives (name, isFirst) resultset - each item starting with "new" letter will have isFirst set to 1 indicating start of new group.

**edit:** Example:

```
CREATE TABLE person(name varchar);
INSERT INTO person SELECT 'Jim' UNION SELECT 'Tom' UNION SELECT 'Ben' UNION SELECT 'John' UNION SELECT 'Alice' UNION SELECT 'Chris' UNION SELECT 'Anna' UNION SELECT 'Jerry';
SELECT p.name, CASE(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM person 
    WHERE name<p.name and SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)=SUBSTR(p.name,1 , 1)
    ) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END isFirst 
FROM person p 
ORDER BY name;
```

gives:

```
Alice|1
Anna|0
Ben|1
Chris|1
Jerry|1
Jim|0
John|0
Tom|1
```

Comment: Great idea but the sample is not working. substring(name) and substring(p.name) are always the same

Comment: Thanks for the example it is working now i overlooked the person p thing at the end.

Comment: By the way you can Re-tag question adding 'sql' and 'sqlite' tags.